# Database Down error while posting a comment through comment box in facebook iframe application

Tags: facebook

I have an iframe application. I have comment box functionality. It is displayed well but the problem comes when i click on post iam getting this error:

**Database Down
Sorry, a temporary error has occurred. Please try again.**

How can i resolve this please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a facebook issue...give it a couple of hours and try again. More importantly make sure you are using the recent comment tags as can be found here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Use the form to generate your code and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is likely due to not using the `xid` parameter. Check that it is there, and if not - adding it should solve your problem.